# Infinitive or Ing

Tags: grammar

> It is more expensive **to buy** this car.
>
> It is more expensive **buying** this car.

In the Cambridge book's exercise there was always a reason why *ing* or *infinitive* were chosen in every sentence. But in that sentence there's no explanation.

Comment: What were the explanations for the other examples and do any of those examples fit this one?

Comment: Their meanings are (lacking context) nigh-on identical; the second sentence is in a less formal register.

Comment: @Greybeard if they did fit, I wouldn't be writing that post :) The book is "First Class B1"

Comment: Extraposition doesn’t extrapose NPs, but only clauses. The fact that gerund-participials are more like NPs than infinitivals are is seen in the fact that they can invert with the subject in interrogatives, and this greater likeness to NPs is reflected in their being less readily extraposed than infinitivals or finite clauses. I haven’t seen a detailed attempt to say when gerund-participials are OK in extraposition, but certainly some cases sound fine. But I remember that in early work in generative grammar it was said simply that extraposition could not apply to gerund-participials.